# How do I boost field score by one of the document's field value?

Tags: solr, lucene

I know that I can give `name^5` to boost that field's score but I want that boost value to be taken from the document.

For the following document, I want to boost the score of name field by 5(value of the field name_weight)

`{
        "id":"IW-02",
        "name":"iPod & iPod Mini USB 2.0 Cable",
        "manu":"Belkin",
        "manu_id_s":"belkin",
        "cat":["electronics",
          "connector"],
        "features":["car power adapter for iPod, white"],
        "weight":2.0,
        "price":11.5,
        "price_c":"11.50,USD",
        "popularity":1,
        "inStock":false,
        "name_weight": 5
}`

Comment: Do you want to apply different weights (from another field) based on which field got the hit, or do you want to boost the general score of the document with the `name_weight` field? I.e. can the `name_weight` boost be applied to all documents in the result set, or just those that matched in the `name` field?

Comment: I want to boost the score of the `name` field of all documents. For example, if I search for `ipod` without any boosting, I get this `3.2535076 = weight(name:ipod in 24) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:  3.2535076 = score(doc=24,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0)`. Here, I want to boost the score returned from `name` field by the value from `name_weight` i.e `3.2535076 ^ 5`

Comment: I assume that this is not the only part of your query and that you have multiple other terms - how would `fq={!boost b=name_weight}name:ipod` work for that specific field? Another option - `boost=name_weight` would apply the boost to the end score and not just the score contributed by the `name` field.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My query will have other terms too. Also, search can be over multiple fields along with their weights, i.e `features` field which can have a `features_weight` field to boost the score of that field.
1. `fq={!boost b=name_weight}name:ipod` won't change the score of that field, right? I want to change the score of that field.
2. Since I will have multiple weight fields (one for each field in the document), I don't want to boost the end score. Instead, each weight field will only boost that field's score.